# CBManager state always unknown

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am trying to check if the bluetooth of a device is on or off. This is the code I've written so far

```
   CBCentralManager *cbManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                                       queue:nil
                                                                     options:
                                   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]
                                                               forKey:CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey]];


    [cbManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:
                                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]
                                                                forKey:CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey]];

    if (cbManager.state==CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    NSString *stateString = nil;
    switch(bluetoothManager.state)
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStateResetting: stateString = @"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent."; break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported: stateString = @"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy."; break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized: stateString = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy."; break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff: stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off."; break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn: stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use."; break;
        default: stateString = @"State unknown, update imminent."; break;
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bluetooth state"
                                                     message:stateString
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitleArray:nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
}
```

The problem is that the state of the manager is always Unknown regardless if the bluetooth on the device is turned on or not.
Any ideas on why this happens ?

Comment: If all your code in the same method? Do you scan before knowing the state?

Comment: Yes, all the code is in the same method. I forgot to delete the part with [self centralManagerDidUpdateState:cbManager]. Also the scaning is there because of an answer I found on stackoverflow. I don't even need to scan for peripherals at this point. I just want to know in which state the bluetooth is

Comment: Are you testing on a real device (not the simulator)?  Is it an iPhone 4s or later or iPad 3 or later?  Have you tried turning the device off and on again?

Comment: I've tested this on two different iPhone 5s with iOS 7

Comment: What is the state of Bluetooth? On or off?  Show your `didUpdateState` method

Comment: I've tried with both Bluetooth on or off. I have edited in the update method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things  -

1. Your `CBCentralManager` should be a property, otherwise it will be released as soon as the method you initialise it in exits
2. You shouldn't call `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` until you are in the powered on state.

   ```
   @property (strong,nonatomic) CBCentralManager *cbManager;



   self.cbManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                                  queue:nil
                                                                options:
                              [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]
                                                                  forKey:CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey]];


   - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
    {
       NSString *stateString = nil;
       switch(central.state)
       {
           case CBCentralManagerStateResetting: 
              stateString = @"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent."; 
              break;
           case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported: 
              stateString = @"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy."; 
              break;
           case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized: 
              stateString = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy."; 
              break;
           case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff: 
              stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off."; 
              break;
           case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn: 
              stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use.";
              [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:
                               [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]
                                                           forKey:CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey]]; 
              break;
           default: 
              stateString = @"State unknown, update imminent."; 
              break;
       }
       UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bluetooth state"
                                                        message:stateString
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitleArray:nil] autorelease];
       [alert show];
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks :) I've done all that, still not working. I am using an SDK that uses bluetooth and I've looked how they have implemented this, I run the debugger on their code and I get the same Unknown state.

Answer (score -1):

the method

> -(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState(CBCentralManager*)central

is called. try to implement this one

> ```
> - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
>   // Possible states that the central manager can return.
>   char *managerStrings[] = {"Unknown Error",            "Resetting",
>                             "Unsupported Device",       "Unauthorized",
>                             "Bluetooth is deactivated", "PoweredOn"};
>
>   NSString *managerString =
>       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", managerStrings[central.state]];
>
>   // the search is enabled if everything is ok
>   if ([managerString isEqualToString:@"PoweredOn"]) {
>
>       //Do something
>
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: if you want i can give you my implemented version of it

Comment: I implemented it and tried to put the if statement there. The state is still Unknown.

Comment: Please do :D I'm all out of solutions

Comment: Nope, still not working. The managerString get the value Unknown Error... :(

Comment: what hardware do you use?

Comment: An iPhone 5 with iOS 7

Comment: you can't continue with this error? Maybe an update to ios8. But if you do this you've to update xcode to 6

Comment: try without options? Im noobie too sry

Comment: No, some screens need to be updated based on the state of the bluetooth. Also I have to enable the bluetooth and if I don't check for the state of the bluetooth the user will be flooded with "Bluetooth allert view" everytime he opens the app. Also, the app needs to work both on iOS 7 and 8

Comment: You get Unknown if the bluetooth is turned on or off?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter, the state will always be Unknown. And I have tried without options

Comment: is your deployment Target < 7.0 don't know if this change something

Comment: The deployment target is >7.0

Comment: maybe one other can you help you better

Comment: initWithDelegate:self

Comment: Yep, the delegate is set

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue after upgrade from Sierra, Xcode 8, Swift 3 to High Sierra, Xcode 9, Swift 4.

- Solution 1: (Just for tests) Wait a second bit between init and start of scan

  ```
  var scanner = BLESensorScanner(sensorName: sensorName);
  sleep(1);
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
      if (scanner.isPoweredOn()) {
          DBG("Bluetooth is powered on");
          scanner.startScan();
      }
      else {
          DBG("Bluetooth is not powered");
          exit(-1);
      }
  }
  ```

Note: `BLESensorScanner` implements `NSObject`, `CBCentralManagerDelegate`, `CBPeripheralDelegate`. `sensorName` is the name of the bluetooth device

- Solution 2: Use event handler to wait until state becomes poweredOn

  ```
  public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
      DBG("CBCentralManager.centralManagerDidUpdateState");
      DBGI("state=\(toString(central.state))");
      if (state == CBManagerState.poweredOn) {
          scanner.startScan();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: There is no BLESensorScanner class

Comment: BLESensorScanner implements NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate. I added a note.